# Using Entity Framework 4 how to filter referenced Entity Collection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using the Entity Framework 4 with C#. I have `Contact` objects that have a referenced Entity collection of `Addresses`. Therefore, one `Contact` can have more than one `Address` entity. What I want to do is filter the returned `Addresses` associated with a `Contact` to only be from the city of Toronto.

Here is the LINQ query I am using but it returns all the `Addresses` as long as at least one has `City == "Toronto"`. I want to limit the `Address` entities returned to only include the `Address` entities have `City == "Toronto"`. How can I structure the LINQ query to do this?

```
var vcontact = from c in context.Contacts
               orderby c.LastName
               where c.Addresses.Any(a => a.City == "Toronto")
               select c;
```

Comment: you want a list of contacts who have an address in Toronto with just the toronto address?

Comment: yes.  I want any contact with at least one address in Toronto and the address entities returned should only include the ones where the city is Toronto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var vcontact = from c in context.Contacts
               orderby c.LastName
               where c.Addresses.Any(a => a.City == "Toronto")
               select new Contact
               {
                   LastName = c.LastName;
                   // map all remaining properties of Contact
                   Addresses = c.Addresses.Where(a => a.City == "Toronto")
               };
```

Comment: Thank you for the code.  The LINQ query fails to compile with Contact used before the braces.  Is there anyway to name the anonymous type like you are trying to do?

Comment: @user31673 - really?  "fails to compile"?  Could you be any more vague?

Comment: @user31673, could you please paste the error you are receiving? `Contact` is not intended to be an anonymous type, it is simply a new instance of your entity. If you want to use a named type instead, create a new class (perhaps `ContactViewModel`) and use that instead of `Contact`.

Comment: Now I understand what you are referring to.  I thought you were creating an anonymous type.  Thank you for your help.